# Projective measurement notation

Tags: quantum-state, linear-algebra, projection-operator

I don't understand how projective measurements work; I think my confusion comes from the notation.

How would this be written in matrix notation?

Is it just [w row vector] [Ma matrix] [w column vector]^T

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> "How would this be written in matrix notation?
> Is it just [w row vector] [Ma matrix] [w column vector]^T"

$|w\rangle$ is a column vector,  and $\langle w|$ is its conjugate transpose (and is a row vector); and yes, $M_a$ is a matrix. Therefore $p(a)$ is a scalar quantity that is obtained by multiplying the row vector $\langle w |$ with the column vector obtained by doing the multiplication: $M_a | w \rangle$.

**None of this is unique to projective measurements, it is just [Dirac's bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation).**

Comment: @FDGod, thanks for improving my answer! I had "transpose" in my head because the author of the question used a "T", but you're right that $\dagger$ would be more appropriate.